# How to check the execution time of cfloop and cfquery?

Tags: coldfusion, query-optimization, cfquery, cfloop

I am having some big queries and loops which gives me an excel output.

I am facing trouble with the performance of excel generation. It takes lot of time. So I thought of optimizing the code, for which I would like to know which block of my code is taking how much time? Can any body help here please?

I just want to know how to dump the execution time of cfquery / cfloop/ cfoutput...?

Comment: For the query part, if you include a result attribute it will include the execution time.

Comment: Yups..It works.. I just added and dumped the result attribute and i can see the execution time.. thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

There is no automated way of seeing the execution time of a block of code in ColdFusion. The granularity is done at file level (or method-call level).

However it's easy enough to do with built-in functions. I do this:

```
startTime = getTickCount()
// block of code to time here
executionTime = getTickCount() - startTime
```

For repeated use, I have rolled this sort of thing into a UDF: http://www.cflib.org/udf/makeStopwatch (requires CF10+ / Railo4+)

Comment: Yeah GetTickCount is a good option but i was wondering whether or not it gives the correct execution time of a CFLOOP. If wrap around the start and end of page i can know that the whole page has taken so so time...but do you think wrapping around cfquery/cfloop gets me accurate time?

Comment: Yeah i think you are right.. its logical. I just tried in one cfquery. it shows me 25 seconds.. It works.. Thanks..

Comment: Yes, it's fine. It's not something I would use to plan a moon landing, but for the purposes of checking slow code, it's fit for purpose. I'd not have suggested it if not ;-)

Comment: Very nice and simple.  I didn't even know this was available...+1 to you sir.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap [**cftimer**](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cftimer) around blocks, which shows times in the debug info (if enabled). Or you can compare two calls to [**getTickCount**](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/gettickcount) to get times in a variable which you can output however you need.

Remember that the first request after a change includes a compilation overhead that doesn't always apply (it can be worthwhile refreshing the page a few times to get an average time).

**For queries in particular**, you can use tools such as [FusionReactor](http://www.fusion-reactor.com/) to check how long it took, without having to modify your code.

Comment: oh yeah.. cftimer, right... wrapping it around my cfloop shows me the time.. Hmm.. let me try that out..thanks Peter...

Comment: But just the cftimer? i mean do i need to include it inside cfoutput?

Comment: Cftimer will function the same way the gettickcount method works, except that it's bundled in a tag with some extra display formatting and can be disabled in the CF administrator.